# Does light of LED depend on current or voltage applied to it?

Tags: voltage, led, current

During a job interview, someone asking me this question: Does the light of an LED depend on the current through it or voltage applied to it?

This seems to be a very beginner question but in fact in background the reality is not quite simple from my point of view.

Everybody says that light of an LED depends only on the current passing through them. But the current depends on the ( applied voltage - cumulative voltages drop ) / the cumulative resistances of each loop. (Vdd - Vf ) / R = I(led)

I also know, that the diode (or LED) is not a linear device.

But from my point of view, current in circuit only depends on the voltage applied. Even for non-linear devices, or complicated things. For instance you cannot have current without voltage but you can have voltage without current.

So, in the end, from my point of view LED light depends on the voltage applied to it because the resulting current will alawys depend on the applied voltage to a given circuit.

Am I clear? How much am I wrong from your point of view?

Comment: There is no single right answer as it always depends why they asked that, but roughly speaking, I would not consider a LED as voltage-operated device, but a current-operated device, as LED light output is almost linearly dependent on the current.

Comment: As there is voltage without current over an ideal isolator, there is current without voltage in an ideal conductor. You can even have voltage of the other direction than the current, for example in a battery.

Comment: "For instance you cannot have current without voltage but you can have voltage without current." Technically, no. Superconductors have current without voltage. Also, "voltage" can mean either p.d. (potential difference) or e.m.f. electromotive force. If you have a copper ring, you can induce a current in it with a varying magnetic field, (it will have an e.m.f.), but (as can be seen by symmetry) all points on the ring have the same "voltage", i.e. there is no potential difference between any two points. (Think of a ring of alternative batteries and resistors, then shrink their sizes).

Answer (score 4):

As an interview question the point might be just to get you to say that it isn't an "either/or" answer — of course the two are interrelated, and you can't have a current without a voltage!

However, consider the way an LED works: every time (well, hopefully most of the time) when an electron and a hole meet at the junction and recombine, a photon is emitted. The number of photons depends on the number of electrons, so the number of photons output per second depends on the charge passing through the device per second — that is, the current.

Comment: Yes for sure. Everyone expect the reply : depend of current. But at each time i can't think avout current in other way as result of a given voltage... But you explanation is physical focused. And help me to see why we say it's current dependant.

Comment: @Dony have you ever heard the term 'diffusion current'? That's a current that is not 'caused' by voltage (I would say 'not related to' voltage but that's semantic).

Answer (score 3):

From [this wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-emitting_diode): -

> **A light-emitting diode (LED) is a semiconductor light source that
> emits light when current flows through it.**

But, you're right in that to get current to flow you need to apply a voltage however, it is the flow of current that causes the effect: -

> **Electrons in the semiconductor recombine with electron holes,
> releasing energy in the form of photons. The color of the light
> (corresponding to the energy of the photons) is determined by the
> energy required for electrons to cross the band gap of the
> semiconductor.**

... And you need a certain amount of voltage to get electrons to flow.